# PDF file closing immediately after opening programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to open a pdf file from sdcard, here is the code of my button in MainActivity class. I am using Android Studio.

```
 public void ShowSDFile(View view) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"im_B030MG.pdf");
    File fileBrochure = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"im_B030MG.pdf");
    if (!fileBrochure.exists())
    {
        CopyAssetsbrochure();
    }

    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(pdfOpenintent, "Open File");
    try {
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Application Available to View PDF",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}





private void CopyAssetsbrochure() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try
    {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
    {
        String fStr = files[i];
        if(fStr.equalsIgnoreCase("abc.pdf"))
        {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try
            {
                in = assetManager.open(files[i]);
                out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + files[i]);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
                break;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Now when I run the application on my mobile and I click the button, I can just see the flash of my pdf file and it get closed automatically.

Here is the output

```
03-15 13:06:33.621 19807-19807/? E/Zygote: v2
03-15 13:06:33.621 19807-19807/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10133
03-15 13:06:33.621 19807-19807/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
03-15 13:06:33.621 19807-19807/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-J700F_5.1.1_0043
03-15 13:06:33.621 19807-19807/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
03-15 13:06:33.621 19807-19807/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-15 13:06:33.631 19807-19807/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: in addTimaSignatureService
03-15 13:06:33.631 19807-19807/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
03-15 13:06:33.631 19807-19807/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKesytore provider
03-15 13:06:33.651 19807-19814/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
03-15 13:06:33.651 19807-19814/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
03-15 13:06:33.661 19807-19807/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: bpa.documentviewer for user  0
03-15 13:06:33.661 19807-19807/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
03-15 13:06:33.661 19807-19807/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
03-15 13:06:33.671 19807-19807/? D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
03-15 13:06:33.671 19807-19807/? D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap bpa.documentviewer
03-15 13:06:33.681 19807-19807/? I/InjectionManager: Constructor bpa.documentviewer, Feature store :{}
03-15 13:06:33.681 19807-19807/? I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
03-15 13:06:33.721 19807-19807/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: bpa.documentviewer for user  0
03-15 13:06:33.721 19807-19807/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: bpa.documentviewer for user  0
03-15 13:06:33.721 19807-19807/? D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
03-15 13:06:33.771 19807-19807/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
03-15 13:06:33.771 19807-19807/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
03-15 13:06:33.871 19807-19807/? D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
03-15 13:06:33.871 19807-19807/? I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : bpa.documentviewer.MainActivity isFragment :false
03-15 13:06:33.881 19807-19839/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-15 13:06:33.901 19807-19807/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
03-15 13:06:33.901 19807-19807/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
03-15 13:06:33.971 19807-19839/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
03-15 13:06:34.001 19807-19839/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-15 13:06:34.021 19807-19839/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-15 13:06:34.021 19807-19839/? D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
03-15 13:06:34.241 19807-19807/? I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :bpa.documentviewer.MainActivity
03-15 13:06:34.241 19807-19807/? I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :bpa.documentviewer.MainActivity
03-15 13:06:34.301 19807-19807/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@6db8aaf time:92699609
03-15 13:06:38.691 19807-19807/bpa.documentviewer D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
03-15 13:06:39.271 19807-19807/bpa.documentviewer D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
03-15 13:06:39.711 19807-19814/bpa.documentviewer W/art: Suspending all threads took: 26.544ms
03-15 13:06:39.861 19807-19839/bpa.documentviewer D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xf4d0ca00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xe10c25a0
03-15 13:06:41.291 19807-19839/bpa.documentviewer D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
03-15 13:06:41.311 19807-19807/bpa.documentviewer I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@6db8aaf time:92706619
03-15 13:07:01.281 19807-19807/bpa.documentviewer D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
03-15 13:07:01.761 19807-19839/bpa.documentviewer D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xf4d0ca00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xe10c22d0
03-15 13:07:03.451 19807-19839/bpa.documentviewer D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
03-15 13:07:03.561 19807-19807/bpa.documentviewer I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@6db8aaf time:92728866
```

Now out put is

03-15 16:06:25.581 25627-25627/bpa.documentviewer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: bpa.documentviewer, PID: 25627
                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 
                                                                     Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1422)
                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1409)
                                                                        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:330)
                                                                        at bpa.documentviewer.MainActivity.ShowSDFile(MainActivity.java:110)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

Now after final change new output is --

03-15 17:36:08.221 28819-28819/bpa.documentviewer D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
03-15 17:36:08.561 28819-28855/bpa.documentviewer D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xf4d0ca00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xe15406b0
03-15 17:36:09.891 28819-28855/bpa.documentviewer D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
03-15 17:36:09.921 28819-28819/bpa.documentviewer I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@6db8aaf time:107491818

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make use of formatting options.

Comment: pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); I don't think this is required.

Comment: @dex - I removed these two lines as suggested but now my app is crashed with message. Unfortunately , myApp has stopped.

Comment: @dex see new output in first post.

Comment: Replace getApplicationContext().startActivity(pdfOpenintent); with simple startActivity(pdfOpenIntent);

Comment: @dex - Thanks for your reply now , i have changed the code, now code is running fine but again PDF is get opened and get closed automatically.    Output is like see orginal post.

Comment: @FlyingKites sorry for late reply, can you add this flag also pdfOpenintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

Comment: still no luck output is    04-02 17:30:33.711 2110-2110/bpa.documentviewer D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-02 17:30:34.291 2110-2146/bpa.documentviewer D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xf490ca00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xe113d710
04-02 17:30:35.801 2110-2146/bpa.documentviewer D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
04-02 17:30:35.841 2110-2110/bpa.documentviewer I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@12339c2f time:222393632

Comment: can you give me some running Code for this process, opening a pdf file from Sd card path? Thanks in Advance.